# ListBox in Windows 8 WinRT app

Tags: listbox, scrollbar

Hi Is there a way to force show vertical scrollbar of ListBox?
I want it to be visible all the time.  I got it to show up when the mouse is over and stay but
I need it to be always shown.

Thank you.